# Having trouble integrating ChatOpenAI with Vercel

Tags: typescript, vercel, openai-api, next.js13

We are trying to host our NextJs13 application with Vercel that includes OpenAI and we are having trouble figuring out why the OpenAI calls are not working. They're working like a charm locally but when we change the api route to our domain, the calls do not work anymore. We also included the environment variables in Vercel and still doesnt work.

```
import { ref, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
import {
  collection,
  query,
  where,
  getDocs,
  addDoc,
  updateDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore/lite";
import { Document } from "langchain/document";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { FaissStore } from "langchain/vectorstores/faiss";
import { OpenAIEmbeddings } from "langchain/embeddings/openai";
import { ChatOpenAI } from "langchain/chat_models/openai";
import { RetrievalQAChain } from "langchain/chains";
import { SystemMessage } from "langchain/schema";
import { HumanMessage } from "langchain/schema";

import { db, storage } from "../../app/firebase";

dotenv.config();
const OPENAI_API_KEY = process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY;

const updateWeeklyInfo = async (REACT_APP_LEAGUE_ID, headlines) => {
  // Reference to the "Weekly Info" collection
  const weeklyInfoCollectionRef = collection(db, "Weekly Headlines");
  // Use a Query to check if a document with the league_id exists
  const queryRef = query(
    weeklyInfoCollectionRef,
    where("league_id", "==", REACT_APP_LEAGUE_ID)
  );
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(queryRef);
  // Add or update the document based on whether it already exists
  if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
    // Document exists, update it
    console.log("in if");
    querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
      await updateDoc(doc.ref, {
        headlines: headlines,
      });
    });
  } else {
    // Document does not exist, add a new one
    await addDoc(weeklyInfoCollectionRef, {
      league_id: REACT_APP_LEAGUE_ID,
      headlines: headlines,
    });
  }
};

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  console.log("what was passed in ", req.body);
  const REACT_APP_LEAGUE_ID = req.body;

  try {
    const readingRef = ref(storage, `files/${REACT_APP_LEAGUE_ID}.txt`);
    const url = await getDownloadURL(readingRef);
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const fileContent = await response.text();
    const newFile = JSON.stringify(fileContent).replace(/\//g, "");
    //console.log("File ", newFile);
    const leagueData = [
      new Document({
        pageContent: [newFile],
        metadata: {
          title: "Fantasy Pulse",
          author: "Fantasy Pulse Editorial Team",
          date: "Sep 1, 2022",
        },
      }),
    ];
    // Process the retrieved data
    const vectorStore = await FaissStore.fromDocuments(
      leagueData,
      new OpenAIEmbeddings()
    );

    const model = new ChatOpenAI({
      temperature: 0.9,
      model: "gpt-4",
      openAIApiKey: OPENAI_API_KEY,
    });
    await vectorStore.save("leagueData");

    const headline = {
      id: "",
      category: "",
      title: "",
      description: "",
    };

    const headlineFormat = JSON.stringify(headline);

    const question = `give me 3 sports style headlines about the league's data, include the scores, who won by comparing their team_points to their opponent's team_points and their star players include a bit of humor as well. I want the information to be in this format exactly ${headlineFormat}, keep description short to one sentence give me the response in valid JSON array format`;

    const chain = RetrievalQAChain.fromLLM(model, vectorStore.asRetriever());
    const apiResponse = await chain.call({ query: question });
    const cleanUp = await model.call([
      new SystemMessage(
        "Turn the following string into valid JSON format that strictly adhere to RFC8259 compliance"
      ),
      new HumanMessage(apiResponse.text),
    ]);
    updateWeeklyInfo(REACT_APP_LEAGUE_ID, cleanUp.content);

    return res.status(200).json(JSON.parse(cleanUp.content));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Unexpected error:", error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: "An error occurred" });
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the hobby or pro tier? I had the same issue on hobby tier and realized that you have to ensure your function executes in less than 10 seconds

Comment: yes im using hobby tier. And thats a good point my function takes more than 10 seconds to generate i will try using pro tier.